# Why doesn't Android Asset Studio Generate ldpi launcher icons?

Tags: android, assets, android-icons

It's all in the title.  It seems that [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html) does not generate ldpi launcher icons.  The tool also seems to generate xxhdpi icons, which aren't mentioned in the [Android launcher icon design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_launcher.html#size)

[image: Android Asset Studio]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think if you also navigate to the res folder in the sdk, you won't find ldpi.

Taken from FAQ of Android Holo Colors Generator, but I think it applies to all the asset studio tools

Why the low density (ldpi) is not generated ?
Android Holo Colors Generator is based upon the default holo theme (in Android source code) which does not provide any picture for low density devices. Moreover, ldpi represents less than 2% of the Android Market Share. Finally, if a device is in ldpi, it will use the mdpi pictures.

Comment: If android can't find a drawable inside the respective density directory it will scale drawables up/down from other folders

Comment: there's a drawable-ldpi folder in all versions of Android and previous revisions of Android Asset Studio clearly supported ldpi.

Comment: @Reda The Download.zip but not enabled for me.

Answer (score 3):

Android Asset Studio no longer^ targets ldpi when generating graphics due to the diminishing market share of ldpi devices. <<< this from the creator's mouth (see for yourself in the comments at https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/dnmfXnKV75R).

You can, however, force the website to run off an older revision simply by adding the revision number to the URL's query portion, like this:

http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-notification.html?r=9ec980e4a634

ths **?r=9ec980e4a634** being the new addition to the normal URL.

^ previous revisions DID target ldpi.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW) G+ post:

> The gorgeous screen on the Nexus 10 falls into the XHDPI density
>   bucket. On tablets, Launcher uses icons from one density bucket up [0]
>   to render them slightly larger. To ensure that your launcher icon
>   (arguably your apps most important asset) is crisp you need to add a
>   144*144px icon in the drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-480dpi folder.

So this is specific to the Nexus 10, and only relevant for the launcher icon (not the screen density in general, that's still xhdpi).

Regarding the ldpi-icon issue: I guess they are simply becoming less relevant, as fewer and fewer devices are sold with a ldpi-density and downscaling from mdpi is probably more "cost-effective" than having an extra image-file in your resources folder.

Answer (score 1):

the documentation of the android guidelines (link [**here**](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)) says :

> Note: Android also supports low-density (LDPI) screens, but you
>   normally don't need to create custom assets at this size because
>   Android effectively down-scales your HDPI assets by 1/2 to match the
>   expected size.